# How can I get my update modal to store the updated values in the database?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I got this modal where I create events, currently, it works perfectly fine and it saves the data on the database.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="createModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <!-- el ID -->
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title " id="createModalLabel">Add Event</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="{{action('CalendarController@store')}}" method="POST">

                    {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src='http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'  width="150px" height="150px" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar" name="image" >
                        </div><hr>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="image">
                                <label class="custom-file-label">Upload picture</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label>Event Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                        <label>Start Date:</label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="start" id="start2">
                        <label>End Date:</label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="end" id="end2">
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <div class="w3-row">
                                <label for="event_category">Event Clasification:</label>
                                <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category" value="C">
                                <label>Competition</label>    
                                <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category"  value="F">
                                <label>Fundraiser</label>    
                                <br>
                                <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category"  value="P">
                                <label>Practice</label>
                                <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category"  value="O">
                                <label>Other</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label>Description:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description">
                        <label>Place:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address">
                        <label>Organizer Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                        <label>Phone:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn btn-primary" type="submit" > Create</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I call this modal with the modal show and enter the values, that are sent to the controller and then saved.

```
 $('#createModal').modal('show')
```

My problem starts with the edit modal,
I can load the values on this modal, but when I try to save them to the DataBase it just doesn't do anything. The page refreshes but the values don't change.

This is my edit modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <!-- el ID -->
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title " >Edit Event</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="{{action('CalendarController@update')}}" method="POST" id="editForm">

                    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="text-center">
                                <img   width="150px" height="150px" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar" name="image" id="image">
                            </div><hr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="image">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label">Upload picture</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <label>Event Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title1" id="title" >
                            <label>Start Date:</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="start1"  id="start" >
                            <label>End Date:</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="end1" id="end" >
                            <br>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <div class="w3-row">
                                    <label for="event_category">Event Category:</label>
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category" id="event-category-C" value="C">
                                    <label>Competition</label>    
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="event_category"  id="event-category-F" value="F">
                                    <label>Fundraiser</label>    
                                    <br>
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category" id="event-category-P" value="P">
                                    <label>Practice</label>
                                    <input class="w3-radio" type="radio"  name="event_category" id="event-category-O" value="O">
                                    <label>Other</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <label>Description:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description1"  id="description">
                            <label>Place:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" id="address">
                            <label>Organizer Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email1" id="email">
                            <label>Phone:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone1" id="phone">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" style="">Delete</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" >
                        <button class="btn btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" > Update Data</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I used to load the values to the Modal, When I click on the event, the modal pops up with that event information.

```
eventClick: function (event) {
                    @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id  != 5)
                        if (event) {
                            $.ajax({
                                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                                type: "PUT",
                                datatype: 'JSON',
                                url: SITEURL + '/fullcalendar/edit',
                                data: "&id=" + event.id,
                                success: function (response) {
                                    event = JSON.parse(response)

                                    if (event.image == null || event.image == '') {
                                        $('#image').attr("src", 'http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png')
                                    } else {
                                        $('#image').attr("src", 'uploads/event/' + event.image)
                                    }
                                    console.log(event)
                                    $('#title').val(event.title)
                                    $('#start').val(formatEventDate(event.start))
                                    $('#end').val(formatEventDate(event.end))
                                    $('#description').val(event.description)
                                    $('#address').val(event.address)
                                    $('#email').val(event.email)
                                    $('#phone').val(event.phone)
                                    let event_category = event.event_category;
                                    $("#event-category-" + event_category).prop("checked", true);

                                    $('#updateModal').modal('show');

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    @endif
                    }
```

Is supposed to go to this function where it saves to the database

```
  public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $id = $request->input('id');

        $this->validate($request,[
            'id'=>'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'start' => 'required',
            'end' =>'required',
        ]);

        $event = Event::find($id);

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() .'.'.$extension;
            $file->move('uploads/event/',$filename);
            $event->image = $filename;
        }

        $event->title = $request->input('title1');
        $event->start = $request->input('start1');
        $event->end = $request->input('end1');
        $event->description = $request->input('description1');
        $event->address=$request->input('address1');
        $event->email=$request->input('email1');
        $event->phone=$request->input('phone1');
        $event->event_category=$request->input('event_category1');
        $event->user_id = $user->id;

        $event->save();

        return redirect('/fullcalendar')->with('success','Data Saved');
    }
```

I have the 2 modal on the same view, each one is called differently and the one that works correctly is the create modal, the update one only shows the data.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have not explained what the problem is other than "it doesn't do anything." Step 1: does a request get sent to the server and is it going to the right URL? Check your browser inspector. Step 2: is the correct method getting run? Check your route list. Step 3: is the controller getting the expected data? Use `dd()`. Step 4: is anything getting saved to the database?

Comment: For all those answers, yes. The problem is that its supposed to store, but it just refreshes the page as it "did it" but the values don't change. 

Right now, I am getting this error: 
Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: fullcalendar/update/{id}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\Tesina-project\resources\views\calendar\index.blade.php)

Comment: I am trying to do this: 

$('#editForm').attr('action','/fullcalendar/update/'+event.id);

and my current route is 

Route::put('fullcalendar/update/{id}','CalendarController@update');

@miken32

Comment: @miken32 Found it!
I was missing this on my ajax 
without it, there was no ID(event) to update. 

$('#id').val(event.id)

Answer (score 0):

It was missing the  $('#id').val(event.id)

```
console.log(event)
                                    $('#id').val(event.id)
                                    $('#title').val(event.title)
                                    $('#start').val(formatEventDate(event.start))
                                    $('#end').val(formatEventDate(event.end))
                                    $('#description').val(event.description)
                                    $('#address').val(event.address)
                                    $('#email').val(event.email)
                                    $('#phone').val(event.phone)
                                    $('#user_id').val(event.user_id)
                                    let event_category = event.event_category;
                                    $("#event-category-" + event_category).prop("checked", true);
                                    $('#updateModal').modal('show');
```